# How to Insert 2 String Into 1 Colomn in Database? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert 2 strings data to 1 colomn(combine) in my `database`.
This is my proccess code.

models:

```
public function edit_code($input_id,$input_name, $input_code){
          $data['name'] = $input_name;
          $data['code'] = $input_code;
          $this->db->where('id',$input_id);
          $this->db->update('code',$data);
        
    }
```

view :

```
<div>  
                            <div>
                            <h2>Edit Code:</h2>
                                <div>
                                <?php echo form_open('login/edit_code');?>
                                <?php 
                                
                                $codeLAT= 'KUCK';

                                $input_name = array(
                                'name'  => 'input_name',
                                'class' => 'forminput',
                                'size' => '30'
                                );
                                
                                $input_code = array(
                                'name'  => 'input_code',
                                'class' => 'forminput',
                                'size' => '30'
                                );
                                                                                                                               
                                ?>

<span>Name</span>: <?php echo form_input($input_name,$page['name']) ?><br/>
<span>Code</span>: <?php echo $codeLAT , form_input($input_code,$page['code']) ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('input_id',$page['id']);?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'class=buttonss'); ?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

controler :

```
public function save_edit_code(){
            
        $this->check_logged_in();
        
        $codeLAT = 'KUCK';

        $input_id = $_POST['input_id'];
        
        $input_name = $_POST['input_name'];
                
        $input_code = ($_POST[$codeLAT]. '' .$_POST['input_code']);
                
        $this->Promo_model->edit_promo($input_id,$input_name, $input_code);
        redirect('login/codepage');
    }
```

In here i want to combine `$codeLAT` with `$inputcode`

> Example :
>
> Script : `$input_code = ($_POST[$codeLAT]. '' .$_POST['input_code']);`
>
> Save in my database colomn `code` : `KUCK009912`

But in my code, my form just save `$inputcode` in my colomn `database`. Not include `$codeLAT`.

In my example just save `009912`.

Comment: check the `input_code ` field type, if its  a `number` then you cannot store string, so change it to `varchar` and it will work.

Comment: sorry the `input_code` its succesfull save to my database. But the `codeLAT` not save. For example my system must save `KUCK00912`, but just `00912` save it in my colomn `code`

Comment: what is field type of that field, integer or varchar ?

Comment: my field varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a clear issue that is being overlooked here.

The form that will be generated by your view will look something like the HTML below.

```
<form action="http://localhost/index.php/login/edit_code" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <span>Name</span>: <input type="text" name="input_name" value="" class="forminput" size="30">
    <br>
    <span>Code</span>: KUCK<input type="text" name="input_code" value="" class="forminput" size="30">

    <input type="hidden" name="input_id" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="buttonss">
</form>
```

As you can see $codeLAT is not a form input and will thus not be sent to the server on form submit.

$_POST is an array that only contains the variables that were passed to the server via the HTTP POST method, which occurs on form submit. Due $codeLAT not being an input in the generated HTML form, the variable will never be added to the $_POST array.

This is why $_POST[$codeLAT] does not retrieve any value. Secondly, if there was a variable named codeLAT in the $_POST array then you would access it using $_POST['codeLAT'].

To make use of $_POST['codeLAT'] you could include it as a hidden input on the form with the following CodeIgniter function.

```
form_hidden('codeLAT', 'KUCK');
```

The codeLAT variable would then be included in the POST method and added to the $_POST array as a result, but would not be visible input to the user.

If you prefer to not add it as a hidden input then you can just access the variable, $codeLAT, as declared in you controller with the following.

```
$input_code = $codeLAT. '' .$_POST['input_code'];
```

I would recommend that you take a look at the [CodeIgniter Form Helper documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_hidden) where the use of the form_hidden function is explained.

I would also recommend that you take a look at the [PHP Form Handling at W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) and an explanation of the [$_POST variable](http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/php/php_post.asp.htm).

Comment: your comment same with the first answer, but with detail information. Thanksyouu

Answer (score 1):

Problem while you storing data in `$input_code` here `$input_code = ($_POST[$codeLAT]. '' .$_POST['input_code']);`

Here you already store data `$codeLAT` so `$_POST` is not needed.

**use below code.**

```
$input_code = $codeLAT. '' .$_POST['input_code'];
```

Comment: Thanks yout code succesfully for me.. but the last answer is very important to another people, because its very detail. Thanksyou for your code :D